# follow select option url on click on button

Tags: jquery, url, hide

I have a select input type in which I have many options with URL value. I also have a button, which shows if any option is selected. But want a way if I choose and option and press the button it should take me to that URL. I am not good in JS. Here is what I did. thanks

```
<form class="center" name="jump">
  <select name="menu">
    <option value="">States</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/alabama/">Alabama</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/alaska-advance-directive-for-health-care/">Alaska</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/arizona-advance-directive-for-health-care/">Arizona</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/arkansas-advance-directive-for-health-care/">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/california-advance-directive-for-health-care/">California</option>
    <option value="https://siteurl.com/product/colorado-advance-directive-for-health-care/">Colorado</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <input class="box" type="button" style="display: inline-block;">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")==""){

                $(".box").hide();
            }
            else{
                $(".box").show();
      $('.box').on('click', function () {
          var url = $(this).attr("value"); 
          if (url) { 
              window.location = url; 
          }
          return false;
      });

            }
        });
    }).change();
});



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("select").change(function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")==""){

            $(".box").hide();
        }
        else{
            $(".box").show();
            var self=this;
  $('.box').on('click', function () {
      var url = $(self).attr("value"); 
      if (url) { 
          window.location = url; 
      }
      return false;
  });

        }
    });
}).change();
});
</script>
```

I think it will work check this link [here](http://codepen.io/m1s/pen/ORgaVx?editors=1011)

Comment: in your code 
`var url = $(this).attr("value");`
in here
`this` indicate different context 
thats why your url containd undifin data